# Permission to create folder on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, permissions, directory

After like a half an our of digging, I've found out I don't have permission to create folders, so how do I get permission to create a folder?

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",downloadLocation,kAmazonCatalogsPrefix]
                          withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                           attributes:nil
                                                error:&error];

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1f18a8b0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/AB570058-4E4A-41B2-9E40-5C93316D6307/eCatalogs, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f18a830 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot modify the contents of a compiled app's bundle folder. This is because the bundle is the compiled application. This prevents the possibility of malware modifying apps after install.

Files generated at run time should be saved to the either `Documents`, `Temp` or `Cache` folders. These folders are only accessible to your app. No other app can access the contents of these folders.

**Sample Code :**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFolderName"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Can I create a folder in the Documents folder?

Comment: @LordZsolt: Yes, that is what I mentioned in my Sample Code. In my sample code, `documentsDirectory` is the Directory Path for `DocumentDirectory`.

Answer (score 7):

Check the below Answer for SWIFT:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

[NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Hello"), withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)]


println(paths)
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged as swift :|

Comment: @LordZsolt No, but it's tagged as iOS so Swift could be useful for some!

Comment: I still really despise the fact that there's a question/answer for the same problem in Obj-C and swift. The solution's the same, only the syntax is different. But +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Except the many times when the swift answer is radically different. Chill.